# Dumbo(Python)/Hadoop unexpected output

Tags: python, encoding, hadoop

I'm trying to execute the following code with dumbo(Python) / haddop
https://github.com/klbostee/dumbo/wiki/Short-tutorial#jobs-and-runners

I followed the tutorial correctly, I have done every step but when I run code in hadoop environment I obtain as output as follows:

*SEQ/org.apache.hadoop.typedbytes.TypedBytesWritable/org.apache.hadoop.typedbytes.TypedBytesWritable�������ޭǡ�q���%�O��������������172.16.1.10������������������172.16.1.12������������������172.16.1.30������*

It should return a list of IP addresses with connections counter.
Why those characters appear? Is it an encoding problem? How do I fix it? Thanks

Also if I try other programs in the tutorial, I have the same problem.

Comment: I have added also .encode('uff-8') to the python source code, but the outcome is the same.

Maybe, I have to configure hadoop in some way, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer by myself. That output is the serialized form of Dumbo. There is no error.

To convert it into a readable text, it's sufficient the follow command (the answer was in the tutorial ! I don't saw it)

```
dumbo cat ipcounts/part* -hadoop /usr/local/hadoop | sort -k2,2nr | head -n 5
```